# Are stdin and stdout actually the same file?

Tags: c, linux, stdout, stdin, io-redirection

I am completely confused, is it possible that stdin, stdout, and stderr point to the same filedescriptor internally? 
Because it makes no difference in C if i want to read in a string from the console if I am using stdin as input or stdout.

`read(1, buf, 200)` works as `read(0, buf, 200)` how is this possible?

(`0 == STDIN_FILENO == fileno(stdin)`,
`1 == STDOUT_FILENO == fileno(stdout)`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the input comes from the console, and the output goes to the console, then all three indeed happen to refer to the same file. (But the console device has quite different implementations for reading and writing.)

Anyway, you should use stdin/stdout/stderr only for their intended purpose; otherwise, redirections like the following would not work:

```
<inputfile myprogram >outputfile
```

(Here, `stdin` and `stdout` refer to two different files, and `stderr` refers to the console.)

Comment: OK so in my case they point to the same file, but how does it then work if I write something to stdout it's also automatically in stdin and stderr but how can I later identify if it got into the stderr pipe for example?

Comment: and wouldn't that crash everthing If I write to stdin with write() and stdin is mapped to my keyboard aren't there errors?

Comment: What pipe? The console device does different things when reading or writing.

Comment: but how does this then internally work if stdin and stdout refer to the same file?

Comment: because if I would write first to the file and later read I should get what I have written before imo?

Comment: The *console device* is the same device in both cases, but has different implementations for `read()` and `write()`.

Comment: but how does read or write call parse to the console device if it wanna read or write?

Comment: `read()` and `write()` are different functions; they also end up as different functions down in the kernel when they reach the console driver. If you were to try to `write()` to a read-only device (e.g., a microphone sound device), it would fail.

Comment: or stdout writeonly protected?

Comment: Because both refer to the same device (file), and that is the place where access rights are handled.

Comment: but wouldn't be it enough to restrict the /proc/id/fd/0 through chmod it with write protection?

Comment: `stdin` is *not* opened by doing `open("/proc/id/fd/0")`, because that entry does not yet exist when the file is not yet open. The actual device file being opened is `/dev/tty` or something like that, and this access check happens only at the `open()` call.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible that stdin, stdout, and stderr point to the same filedescriptor internally?

A [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) is an index into the file descriptor table of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (see also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)...). By definition `STDIN_FILENO` is 0, `STDOUT_FILENO` is 1, annd `STDERR_FILENO` is 2. Read about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to query information about some process (for example, try `ls -l /proc/$$/fd` in your interactive shell).

The program (usually, but not always, some [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)) which has [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-d your executable might have called [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) to share (i.e. duplicate) some file descriptors.

See also [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and read some Linux programming book, such as the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf).

Notice that [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) from `STDOUT_FILENO` could fail (e.g. with [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) being `EBADF`) in the (common) case where stdout is *not* readable (e.g. after [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) by the shell). If reading from the console, it could be readable. Read also [*the Tty Demystified*](https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

Answer (score 2):

One thing that some people seem to be overlooking: `read` is the low-level system call. Its first argument is a Unix file descriptor, not a `FILE*` like `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. You should be getting a compiler warning about this:

```
    warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   int r = read(stdout, buf, 200);
                ^~~~~~
```

On my system, it doesn't work with either `stdin` or `stdout`. `read` always returns `-1`, and `errno` is set to `EBADF`, which is "Bad file descriptor". It seems unlikely to me that those exact lines work on your system: the pointer would have to point to memory address 0, 1 or 2, which won't happen on a typical machine.

To use `read`, you need to pass it `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO` or `STDERR_FILENO`.

To use a `FILE*` like `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr`, you need to use `fread` instead.

Comment: in my programm i used 0,1 as input i only typed there stdin stdout for abstraction

Comment: @Fernadiniho you should make that clear in your question as `stdin` and `stdout` are identifiers defined in `stdio.h` which is usually included in about every C console program.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing prohibiting any number of file-handles referring the same thing in the kernel.

And the default for a terminal-program is to have `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` refer to the same terminal.

So, it might look like it doesn't matter which you use, but it will all go wrong if the caller does any handle-redirection, which is quite common.
The most common is piping output from one program into the input of the next, but keeping stdout out of that.

An example for the shell:

```
source | filter | sink
```

Answer (score 0):

Programs such as **login** and **xterm** typically open the tty device *once* when creating a new terminal session, and *duplicate* the file descriptor two or three times, arranging for file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 to be linked to the *open file description* of the opened tty device.  They typically close all other file descriptors before exec-ing the shell. So if no further redirection is done by the shell or its child processes, the file descriptors, 0, 1 and 2, remain linked to the same file. Because the underlying tty device was opened in read-write mode, all three file descriptors have both read and write access.