# fd0 vs fd1 on libevent event_base

Tags: c++, libevent, event-based-programming

I have a simple event_base setup where I create an event to do a callback whenever data on fd 0 is ready

```
void callback(int fd, short event, void* arg) { // (1)
  string s;
  cin >> s;
  cout << "I am in callback" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  event_base* eb = event_base_new();
  event* event = event_new(eb, 0, EV_READ | EV_PERSIST, callback, NULL);
  event_add(event, nullptr);
  event_base_dispatch(eb);
  return 0;
}
```

Now in this case, when I run the program and enter a keyword, "hello", callback() gets called as expected and it prints out "I am in callback", however, since this print happens on the shell, which is where fd0, fd1 point to, why doesn't the callback trigger again because data is ready for fd0 again right since fd0 points to shell only?

I understand that STDIN and STDOUT are 2 different things, but they both point to shell only

Comment: If a program prints "hello world" on its standard output and then immediately tries to read its standard input, do you expect it to immediately read "hello world" on its standad input? Even if both standard input and output is the terminal shell?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik if I am using read system call with fd = 0 or 1, then isn't that the right expectation? Why would stdin not be ready with "hello world"? My understanding is not thorough here, what mistake am i making?

because, I if i provide an input to stdin and do read(fd=1), it does read it

Comment: STDIN and STDOUT don't "point to" the shell.  The shell sends data you type into your terminal to the program's STDIN and prints data that the program writes to its STDOUT to the terminal.  That doesn't mean they're the same thing though; the shell knows whether it's reading or writing.

Comment: @MilesBudnek but in this case, I am working with raw file descriptors, shouldn't the same concept of using read(fd=1) on read from stdin apply here as well? I think what you are saying will work if I am using stdin, stdout as streams, but in this case I am using raw descriptors, so what is stopping fd1 to not have the data, but its not stopping me to use read(fd=1) on read from stdin?

Comment: I am also referring to raw file descriptors.  Even if fd 0 and fd 1 refer directly to the tty device file (as opposed to a pair of pipes or similar), that "file" is not a simple blob of data.  It sends data to your terminal, which is a program (or, in theory, a physical device) that can apply different behavior depending of if it was read from or written to.

Comment: @MilesBudnek oh i see, that makes sense...however, why does these 2 things happen then:
a) reading from stdin using read(fd=1) works, that tty file should make sure its read only from fd0 right?

b) If i create an event handler in the above code with fd=1, then when I run the program and enter "hello world" from terminal, both callback for fd0 and fd1 gets called, i.e. both fd's have data in it...so why does that happen and not what I am expecting?

Comment: In the case of a shell running directly in a terminal emulator fd 0, 1, and 2 will, by default, all refer to the same open file description (the kernel structure representing an open file), so you can read and write any of them.  That isn't always the case though.  I.e. if you did `some-command | your-program > some-file.txt` then fd 0 will refer to the read end of a pipe, fd 1 will refer to a file (likely open in write-only mode), and fd 2 will refer to the tty device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532911/are-stdin-and-stdout-actually-the-same-file

Comment: @MilesBudnek i understand that when you do some-command | your-program > some-file.txt, then fd0, fd1 changes....but in my case, I am not doing anything of that sort....when I look at /prod/<pid>/fd, both 0 and 1 point to same /dev/tty/18, so I still don't understand the event base is not working. 

Sam, unfortunately, that link doesn't explain what I am looking for....it states that in case of console, fd0, fd1 point to same file but with different read/write implementations, however, i am able to read via stdout and write via stdin

Comment: You're able to read from stdout and write to stdin because they refer to the same file-like-thing: the psudeo-tty device.  That thing isn't actually a file though; the kernel is just presenting it like a file.  In reality, when you write to it, those writes get funneled to another process that's reading from the other end, and when you read from it you get what the process at the other end wrote to it.  It's basically two pipes in a trenchcoat.  Since it's really just a way to funnel data from one process to another, the processes at each end get to decide what that data means.

Comment: @MilesBudnek that makes more sense to me now actually...so do you think in case of this event_base, there is something special going on? Because if i create event for fd1, and give an input in terminal, both callbacks for fd0 and fd1 get called...so this means there is some special logic present where when I cout in fd0 callback, that fd0 doesn't become active again? i can. make my peach by just assuming there's something going on, but what that something exactly is seems unknown to be honest

Comment: There is nothing special going on.  Your event is configured to fire when data is available to read on the selected file descriptor.  When you type something on the terminal it can be seen through either file descriptor.  When you write to stdout, data becomes available for _the terminal_ to read from its file descriptor referencing the master end of the pty.  Nothing is available for your your process to read from either of its file descriptors referencing the slave end of the pty and so no event is fired.

Comment: I think your base misconception is that the file descriptors in your process somehow reference the data in the terminal's screen buffer.  They do not.  That's just a big `char[]` in the terminal emulator process's memory space.  What it chooses to show there is totally unrelated to what either it or your process writes to or reads from the file descriptors referencing your shared pty device.

Comment: @MilesBudnek yeah my understanding is mostly wrong here....my main confusion lies in the fact that if i provide event handlers for both fd0 and fd1, and then provide some data from terminal, both fd0 and fd1 handlers get called...so how can I prevent that because I am seeing different behaviors when I do cout, vs when I provide input from stdin, which is what triggered this whole post

Comment: I wrote an answer with some pictures to hopefully help.

Comment: @MilesBudnek thanks, that answer is what I exactly needed and where I was struggling to visualize...this helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your program from a shell running in a terminal emulator, assuming you didn't do any extra redirection, you'll end up with file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 (stdin, stdout, and stderr) all referencing the slave end of a [pseudo-terminal device](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html) (abbreviated pty) that the terminal emulator owns the master end of.

That is, you have this:
[image: A process and its file descriptors referencing a pty device]

A pseudo-terminal is essentially a bidirectional pipe (with some extra functionality like raising SIGINT when a `^C` character is written to the master end).  That is, data that gets written to the master end can be read from the slave end, and data that gets written to the slave end can be read from the master end.  That is, data flows like this:
[image: Data flow through a pty device]

It DOES NOT flow like this:
[image: Wrong data flow through a pty]

That means that when your process writes to its stdout or stderr (or stdin, but you shouldn't) file descriptors the terminal emulator can read that data and print it out to the screen, and when you type data into the terminal emulator, it will write that data to its end of the pty device and your process can read that data via its stdin (or stdout or stderr, but again, you shouldn't) file descriptor.

Data written to the slave end of the pty cannot be read back from the slave end though.  Only from the master end.  That means that data your writes to its stdout file descriptor is not available to be read from its stdin file descriptor, since both reference the slave end of the pty.

Notice that this pty device is completely separate from the way the terminal emulator presents the data.  The fact that data you type into your terminal emulator and data your process writes to the pty device usually get written to the same window is irrelevant.  The terminal emulator could just as well send its output to a teletype to be printed onto paper or it could commission a skywiter to fly over your house and write your process's output in smoke and the pty mechanism by which your process exchanges data with the terminal emulator would be completely unchanged.

---

Returning to your original question: `callback` does not get executed when you write to stdout because you've configured libevent to call `callback` when data is available to be read from stdin, and data written to stdout is not available to be read from stdin.  It can only be read from the master end of the pty device, and only the terminal emulator has a file descriptor referencing that.  stdout and stdin both reference the slave end of the pty, and data written to the slave end cannot be read back from the slave end.